# How to set the background color of a page for scroll pull?

Tags: css, scroll, background, touch

With touch devices (mobile, touchpads, etc.) I need to set the background-color of a page when scrolling off the body:

[image: scroll off]

I tried setting the background color of the HTML:

```
html {
   background-color:#00BD9C;
}
```

It worked as seen on the movie. However I need a white background-color for the bottom of the page. background-image for html doesn't work with scrolling off. I thought of using a gradient. Is there a better way?

Comment: What tool did you use to make that GIF?

Comment: https://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you manage to have it working?

Comment: @Sergio used javascript to change the background color

Comment: I experienced an ugly background color and wanted to remove it. So I can from the other side. I found no CSS but after some try and error I discovered

<meta name="theme-color" content="#DE0000">

in my <head> which set the color for Safari on macOS and iOS. Hope this helps.

Comment: I just had this problem and thought I'd outsmart it by using background linear-gradient. No such luck, apparently "background-color" for the html element is somewhat special.

Answer (score 7):

When setting a background to the html, it will be applied on all four borders. If you just want to have a background-color on e.g. the top site, add a `div` element to your DOM to be displayed above your page:

```
<div style="height:1000px;background:#00BD9C;margin-top:-1000px;position:fixed;width:100%;"></div>
```

By that, the overflow color will just be applied on the top side.

Or you could also add it in pure CSS:

```
html:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 999px;
  top: -999px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

Comment: In Safari, this did not working for me unless I changed top to `-999px`

Comment: I also needed to use margin-top: `-999px` which made a 1 pixel line visible... which was removed using `z-index: -1`.